# moving BQ (bigquery) table to GCS (google cloud storage) using R

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How would I move the table from big query to google cloud storage using R? I was looking into big query library, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Using the bigrquery [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrquery/index.html), you can use the bq_table_save() function, found it in the [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrquery/bigrquery.pdf).

> Export a .csv file to Cloud Storage using bq_table_save()

As a general recommendation, take a look at the information provided for the [packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrquery/index.html), a quick search in the reference manual or docs may save you a lot of time.

Comment: Just a note for anyone encountered the same issue as me - If you find your exported file in a messed up format, try specifying destination_format = "CSV" in bq_table_save(). It's using "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON" by default (at least in my case...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use export:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

```
bq --location=location extract \
--destination_format format \
--compression compression_type \
--field_delimiter delimiter \
--print_header=boolean \
project_id:dataset.table \
gs://bucket/filename.ext
```

Comment: Thanks, Felipe, how would I do that using R?